# Understanding Lebesgue Measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the Lebesgue measurable definition by Stein and Shakarchi (2009).

The authors state:

> "A subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is Lebesgue measurable if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an open set $O$ with $E\subset O$ and $m_*(O-E)\leq\epsilon$.

*My Question:*

1. Is my understanding of the definition correct?

Consider a subset $E$. If for any arbitrarily small number, if you could find a big open set $O$ containing $E$ such that when you fit the closed cubes that fit the difference between these two sets, the volume of this difference is virtually zero.

In other words, if you can find one big open cover for $E$ such that we can make the difference between this open cover and $E$ to be virtually none from the standpoint of fitting the small closed cubes, then we say $E$ is measurable.

Is there a better and more intuitive way of interpreting the definition above?

Reference:
*Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces*. Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi. Princeton University Press, 2009.

Comment: You’ve got it. Just make sure to know that there is a difference between m(O—E) and m(O) -m(E). For any set, and for any epsilon, you can find an open set O s.t. m(O)-m(E)<epsilon. But it is not always possible to do get m(O-E)<epsilon

Comment: @Ovi Thank you!

Comment: No problem! ${}$